# Filter out column in array where all instances have a value of 0

Tags: php, arrays, filter

I have a 2-dimensions array as such:

```php
$input = array(
    "Category 1" => array(
        "Name 1" => array(
            "value" => 1,
            // ... other keys, doesn't matter
        ),
        "Name 2" => array(
            "value" => 0,
        ),
        "Name 3" => array(
            "value" => 0,
        ),
    ),
    "Category 2" => array(
        "Name 1" => array(
            "value" => 8,
        ),
        "Name 2" => array(
            "value" => 0,
        ),
        "Name 3" => array(
            "value" => 12,
        ),
    ),
);
```

Note that every `Category N` have the sames `Name N` keys, only `value` changes.

I want to filter out entries where `value=0` in every dimensions, as such:

```php
$ouput = array(
    "Category 1" => array(
        "Name 1" => array(
            "value" => 1,
            // ... other keys, doesn't matter
        ),
        "Name 3" => array(
            "value" => 0,
        ),
    ),
    "Category 2" => array(
        "Name 1" => array(
            "value" => 8,
        ),
        "Name 3" => array(
            "value" => 12,
        ),
    ),
);
```

- `Name 1` **remains** due to value!=0 in both `Category N`
- `Name 2` is **filtered out** due to  *value=0* in both `Category N`
- `Name 3` **remains** due to *value=12* in `Category 2`

---

My first thought was using [array_intersect()](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.array-intersect.php).
But since `$input` is dynamic I don't how many dimensions it has (nor their names).

**Maybe if we could *explode* a multi-dimensional array into *array per dimension*?** I'm not sure this is the best way to go.

Every hint is appreciated.

Comment: Not entirely sure that your title matches your question.

Comment: imo, It isn't that difficult to do. It is just really expensive.  What size datasets are you using this on. just curious.

Comment: @NigelRen Not sure how I could explain it simply

Comment: @RyanVincent Not more than 5-8 categories / 100 names

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does the job.  Basically loop through the first category (as they all have the same Name values) and extract all of the fields for each particular Name N values.  If the sum of these values is 0 (there are other similar methods if you may have negative numbers) then remove all of these fields...

```
foreach ( current($input) as $name => $value ) {
    // Extract all values
    $nameValues = array_column(array_column($input, $name), "value");
    if ( array_sum($nameValues) == 0 )  {
        // remove values (use & to allow to modify values)
        foreach ( $input as &$categories )   {
            unset ($categories[$name]);
        }
    }
}
print_r($input);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a recursive function to navigate through your array.

```
function Clean($input){
    if (is_array($input)){
        foreach($input as $key=>$value){
            $output=Clean($value);
            if ($output===null){
                return 0;
            }elseif($output==0){
                unset($input[$key]);
            }else{
                $input[$key]=$output;
            }
        }
        return $input;  
    }else{
        if ($input==0){
            return null;
        }else{
            return $input;
        }
    }
}
```

Example:

```
<?php

function Clean($input){
    if (is_array($input)){
        foreach($input as $key=>$value){
            $output=Clean($value);
            if ($output===null){
                return 0;
            }elseif($output==0){
                unset($input[$key]);
            }else{
                $input[$key]=$output;
            }
        }
        return $input;  
    }else{
        if ($input==0){
            return null;
        }else{
            return $input;
        }
    }
}

$input = array(
    "Category 1" => array(
        "Name 1" => array(
            "value" => 1,
            // ... other keys, doesn't matter
        ),
        "Name 2" => array(
            "value" => 0,
        ),
        "Name 3" => array(
            "value" => 0,
        ),
    ),
    "Category 2" => array(
        "Name 1" => array(
            "value" => 8,
        ),
        "Name 2" => array(
            "value" => 0,
        ),
        "Name 3" => array(
            "value" => 12,
        ),
    ),
);



echo "input:";
var_dump($input);

$output=Clean($input);

echo "output:";
var_dump($output);

//exit;

$input = array(
    "Name 1" => array(
        "value" => 1,
        // ... other keys, doesn't matter
    ),
    "Name 2" => array(
        "value" => 0,
    ),
    "Name 3" => array(
        "value" => 0,
    )
);

echo "input:";
var_dump($input);

$output=Clean($input);

echo "output:";
var_dump($output);

$input = array(
    "Category A" => array(
        "Cat B" => array(
            "Name 1" => array(
                "value" => 1,
                // ... other keys, doesn't matter
            ),
            "Name 2" => array(
                "value" => 0,
            ),
            "Name 3" => array(
                "value" => 0,
            )
        )
    )
);

echo "input:";
var_dump($input);

$output=Clean($input);

echo "output:";
var_dump($output);


?>
```

Result:

```
input:array(2) {
  ["Category 1"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["Name 1"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["value"]=>
      int(1)
    }
    ["Name 2"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["value"]=>
      int(0)
    }
    ["Name 3"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["value"]=>
      int(0)
    }
  }
  ["Category 2"]=>
  array(3) {
    ["Name 1"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["value"]=>
      int(8)
    }
    ["Name 2"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["value"]=>
      int(0)
    }
    ["Name 3"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["value"]=>
      int(12)
    }
  }
}
output:array(2) {
  ["Category 1"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Name 1"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["value"]=>
      int(1)
    }
  }
  ["Category 2"]=>
  array(2) {
    ["Name 1"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["value"]=>
      int(8)
    }
    ["Name 3"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["value"]=>
      int(12)
    }
  }
}
input:array(3) {
  ["Name 1"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["value"]=>
    int(1)
  }
  ["Name 2"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["value"]=>
    int(0)
  }
  ["Name 3"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["value"]=>
    int(0)
  }
}
output:array(1) {
  ["Name 1"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["value"]=>
    int(1)
  }
}
input:array(1) {
  ["Category A"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Cat B"]=>
    array(3) {
      ["Name 1"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["value"]=>
        int(1)
      }
      ["Name 2"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["value"]=>
        int(0)
      }
      ["Name 3"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["value"]=>
        int(0)
      }
    }
  }
}
output:array(1) {
  ["Category A"]=>
  array(1) {
    ["Cat B"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["Name 1"]=>
      array(1) {
        ["value"]=>
        int(1)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: why do you have 'name 2' in the output array when all the entries for name 2 are zero? The 'expected result' is provided in the question. If you pass a 'flag' as a reference to keep all the entries in your recursive function? Then you know whether to write the entry to the output array even when it is zero?

Comment: @RyanVincent, Where are you seeing output with value 0? There isn't any value 0 in output.

Comment: Your answer almost does it. Unfortunately, it justs checks if the value is equal to 0, regardless the value for the same `Name` in others `Category`. `Name 3` is filtered out in `Category 1` but it shouldn't. Thanks though!